# Find and replace with hash key values in r

Tags: r

I have a function as follows:

```
HistolMacDescrip <- function(dataframe, MacroColumn) {
  dataframe <- data.frame(dataframe)

  # Column specific cleanup
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Dd]ictated by.*", "")
  # Conversion of text numbers to allow number of biopsies to be extracted
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Oo]ne", "1")
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Ss]ingle", "1")
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Tt]wo", "2")
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Tt]hree", "3")
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Ff]our", "4")
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Ff]ive", "5")
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Ss]ix", "6")
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Ss]even", "7")
  dataframe[, MacroColumn] <- str_replace(dataframe[, MacroColumn],
                                          "[Ee]ight", "8")
  return(dataframe)
}
```

I think the amount of repetition is a little ridiculous and the code could be neater. I wondered if a key-value find and replace line could be used instead.

One of the problems is that the input may contain more than one literal number so that the find and replace shouldn't stop once the first match is found.

**Example input**

```
d<-c("There are two specimens","Three exist here","Two three four")
d<-data.frame(d)
```

**Example output**

```
"There are 2 specimens",
"3 exist here",
"2 3 4"
```

Comment: If you have more than one match, use `str_replace_all`,.  Also, looks like, the code can be made compact with a `for` loop with replacement and matching patterns as vectors

Answer (score 0):

We could make use of `english` with `gsubfn`

```
library(english)
library(gsubfn)
sub("^([a-z])", "\\U\\1",  gsubfn("\\w+", setNames(as.list(2:4), 
   as.character(english(2:4))), tolower(as.character(d$d))), perl = TRUE)
#[1] "There are 2 specimens" "3 exist here"          "2 3 4"
```